tbb freezes glfw window
When I use tbb::parallel_invoke to separate the input loop from the render loop into two different threads, both loops are running, but the window from glfw freezes immediately.
The following is the trimmed down version of the code that still yields the error, note that the relevant part is the main function:
#include <glad/glad.h>
// glad needs to be included before GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <tbb/tbb.h>
#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

class Window
{
public:
    unsigned int const SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    unsigned int const SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    GLFWwindow* w;

    Window()
    {
        glfwInit();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#ifdef __APPLE__
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, false);

        w = glfwCreateWindow(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, "Simulation", nullptr, nullptr);
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);

        // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
        // ---------------------------------------
        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            throw -1;
        }

        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(w, framebuffer_size_callback);

        // OpenGL configuration
        // --------------------
        glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Window window;
    tbb::parallel_invoke(
        [&]() -> void // Simulation
        {
            while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.w))
            {
                std::cout << "Render loop" << std::endl;
                glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
                glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

                glfwSwapBuffers(window.w);
                glfwPollEvents();
            }
        },

        []() -> void // Input and Time
        {
            while (true)
            {
                std::cout << "Input loop" << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            }
        });
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

As you can see these loops are completely separated from each other.
Deleting the while loop from the input (e.g. just outputting "input loop" once) fixes the issue and the program runs perfectly even within the invoke.
Interesting is also that the output in the render loop also continues, while the window freezes. Meaning both threads must still be running.
I have also tried using tbb::task_group/tbb::task_arena but the same issues arise.
Using OpenMP works fine, but I wanted to try using tbb.

"Most GLFW functions must only be called from the main thread (the thread that calls main), but some may be called from any thread once the library has been initialized. Before initialization the whole library is thread-unsafe."

Thank you very much for your comment! I am surprised that the same code structure works with OpenMP though. Also the only glfw function I am using within the thread is glfwWindowShouldClose which is marked as okay by your link. Am I overlooking something?

Run all the GLFW init & window creation on the main thread and pass the GLFWWindow* off to the worker thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792242/

To elaborate more on genpfaults comment: You have to check in the glfw docs the "Thread safety" section for each method. glfwWindowShouldClose and glfwSwapBuffers can be called from anywhere, but glfwPollEvents needs to be called on the main thread.

Oh, I see. I completely overlooked them yesterday, thanks!

@Steegi Did this solve the issue, i.e. answer your question?

@Yun hi, yes it did

Thanks. Someone should write an answer, ideally @genpfault since he solved the issue first. Or Steegi themselves. I can also do it, just let me know.
